# docker run complains file not found

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am running following command for build docker image from /etc/docker and all files I want to copy inside the container are at this same location

```
docker build -t user/testapp .
```

Following is the content of my Dockerfile:-

```
FROM openjdk:alpine
COPY . /usr/src/testapp/
WORKDIR /usr/src/testapp/
CMD TestAppStart
```

Image builds fine but when running it uwing following command it says:-
   /bin/sh: /usr/src/testmq/TestAppStart
I also tried absolute path in CMD but same error.

I have verified that the files are getting copied by changing CMD to /bin/sh the container starts and I get a shell inside it and I can navigate to that directory and see all the files and can even run the TestAppStart from there manually.

Need help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The /usr/src/testapp/ directory is not in the PATH environment variable, so /bin/sh complains.

Change the last line to:

```
CMD ./TestAppStart
```

Comment: isn't workdir command supposed to set the folder to where TestAppStart is present

Comment: No.  The WORKDIR command is like a "cd" or chdir command to set the current directory of the process.

Comment: yes 5 more minutes please, it says cannot do that within sometime.